# Google Tango C API, compilation of single APK for every device

Tags: android, google-project-tango

I'm trying to prepare a single APK for my game for both Tango and non-Tango devices. (Tango-specific features will not be available on regular devices). I'm using C native API.
Running the app on a non-tango device always throws an exception

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: could not load library "libtango_support_api.so" needed by "libtroikaproject.so"; caused by could not load library "libcxsparse.so" needed by "libtango_support_api.so"; caused by library "libcxsparse.so" not found
```

- Is it possible to link with Tango libraries so that the app could be
  launched on regular devices without error?
- Is it possible to use "Multiple APK" mechanism to publish
  single app on Google Play for Tango and regular devices?

Comment: dsylla, what device you are using? Multiple APK is possible, but you will need to specify different build flavors in gradle. I suspect that the crash is caused by architecture differences, the current Tango device (the tablet) is arm based, and the libtango_support_api.so is arm .so too. If you run it on another ABI, it will crash the app. But that's just my guess, let me know your device information so I could be more specific.

Comment: My current Tango device is "Project Tango Tablet Development Kit", I'm using the latest so libs. The apk with the tango libraries crashes on Galaxy S3 / 4.1.2, OnePlusOne 5.0.2 and probably on every non-tango devices. I'm compiling the project with APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a architecture.

Comment: Hi Dsylla, I think we've found the issue. libcxsparse.so is a library that we dynamically linked in libtango_support_api.so. On Tango device, we actually put a libcxsparse in system/lib. But on any other devices, the lib is not there. We are working on removing the dependency of the libcxsparse.so in the support library. As the temp fix, I think you could download the libcxsparse from their website:https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=devel(libcxsparse) and package it in to your APK's lib folder. Sorry about the bug, but thanks for reporting it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Is it possible to link with Tango libraries so that the app could be launched on regular devices without error?

Yes, it is possible. The error is caused by how Tango links the library internally, and it is going to be fixed soon. As the temp fix, you could download the libcxsparse.so from their [website](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=devel(libcxsparse)) and package it in to your APK's lib folder.

- Is it possible to use "Multiple APK" mechanism to publish single app on Google Play for Tango and regular devices?

Multiple APK is possible, but you will need to specify different build flavors in gradle. This is currently not there in the sample code.

Comment: I couldn't find it in rpm, but just copied the so file from Tango device and it compiles and works like a charm. Thanks Jason!